# Django form not submitting in POST

Tags: django, post, django-forms

Been having an issue where I am unable to upload files into my form. From what I can gather on my own, it's because I'm not submitting in POST (since uploaded files aren't saved unless you're in POST) but I don't know why that's the case. Here's my code:

Views.py

```
def commission(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommissionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        subject = str(form.cleaned_data.get("name")) + "'s commission request"
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("name") + ",\nhas requested a commission, with the following request:\n" + form.cleaned_data.get("request") + "\n Reply to them using their email:\n" + form.cleaned_data['email']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        attach = request.FILES['reference']
        try:
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
            if attach != None:
                mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
            mail.send()
            return redirect("main-commissions-success")
        except:
            return render(request, "main/commissions.html", {"form": form})
    return render(request, "main/commissions.html", {"form": form})

else:
    form = CommissionForm()

return render(request, "main/commissions.html", {"form": form})
```

Commissions.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content-section card w-50 mx-auto my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="" class="border border-light m-10" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 text-center">Request A Painting</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Send Request</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And since this has no model relation, I'm not going to bother adding it here. Hopefully someone can help point out whatever dumb mistake I've made lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong so, for anyone else with a similar issue, I had forgotten to request the files from the post request. So this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
form = CommissionForm(request.POST)
```

is meant to be this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
form = CommissionForm(request.POST, request,FILES)
```

in order to access your files.